# R: How do i finish the tails in the risk neutral density, obtained from option prices

Tags: options, black-scholes, implied-volatility, risk-neutral-measure, density

Im currently working on constructing the risk neutral probability distribution of a stock, based on the option prices. In doing so, i calculate the implied volatilities from the option prices, and then construct densities.

I have not yet normalized the densities in the plot below.

As the expiration date increases, more of the right-tail disappears.

My Question: How do i fit/model the "missing" tails in these densities?

[image]

When looking for solutions online, i only encounter examples where we have some dataset X, and then fit a density() to that, but given the problem here, i dont have a dataset, and therefore have to "extend" the density, by fitting some relationship, to extrapolate.

The work i am trying to replicate from matlab is: https://se.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/estimating-option-implied-probability-distributions-for-asset-pricing.html
where in matlab the author uses:

```
for k = 1:numel(T0)
    pdfFitsCall{k} = fit(pdfK, approxCallPDFs(:, k), 'linear');
end
```

This is my first question, so hopefully there is enough information in my question.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you elucidate what you used to interpolate the density in the first place? The prices are not available across a contiguous set of strikes, so there must be an assumption somewhere in your code.

Comment: I fit a polynomial model to my calculated implied volatilities, with respect to the strike price, and then use the fitted model to calculate alot of implied volatilities for a sequence of strike prices. This way i get more data:  ```smile_model <- lm(data[[i]]$implied.volatility ~ data[[i]]$Strikes + I(data[[i]]$Strikes^2))   ```

Comment: I see. Can you not extrapolate by using the same polynomial? (I'm not recommending this, but I'm trying to see what your criteria of a good fit would be).

Comment: I could try and do that. I know its not the most sophisticated approach. I just tried solving the problem as the matlab code i linked, where it seems like the author extends the densities strictly by fitting something to the densities, and not the implied volatility model. But i will go with this for now. Thank you for a quick response. :)

Comment: Sure thing. Just make sure there is no arbitrage - this could come into play as the slope of the IV smile is bounded by some no arbitrage restrictions if I remember correctly. All you need to do is check that the density is non negative, call prices are decreasing with strike, and convex in strike.

Comment: Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Fit a Lognormal mixture and you're fine with extrapolation, too.

Comment: You could fit the SVI parametrization of [Gatheral & Jacquier](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2033323) of the IV smile to your implied volatilities, which has a very good fit. Then you would have a closed form formula for the RNDs. If you were to extrapolate the RNDs, you would also make sure that they still integrate to one. (...)

Comment: (...) Alternatively check [Aït-Sahalia & Lo](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andrew_Lo/publication/3627855_Nonparametric_estimation_of_state-price_densities_implicit_infinancial_asset_prices/links/55aa6ecd08ae481aa7fbc1b4/Nonparametric-estimation-of-state-price-densities-implicit-infinancial-asset-prices.pdf). I think they were the first to do this. I have also done this by fitting the polynomial $\sigma(K, \tau)=\beta_0 + \beta_1\left(\frac{K}{F_t}\right)+\beta_2\left(\frac{K}{F_t}\right)^2+\gamma_1\tau+\gamma_2\tau^2$ by means of a regression and then used Breeden & Litzenberger formula

Comment: would you mind sharing your code for deriving the densities? I got stuck and none of my graphs look legit. Thank you very much in advance!